How to support long hanging pipes near joist
I installed a new water heater and the contractor ran pipes which are poorly supported. I was thinking of using mounting ties and screwing it to the joist.
What would be the most appropriate thing to do/use?


Are you worried about the PVC vent pipe, or the PEX (which presumably goes to the WH, but we don't know since you didn't include that in the pic)?

Lowe's sells j-shaped plastic pipe hangers that are nailed to the joist

As do other hardware providers, of course. And metal straps, and other solutions.
